# Help with a Conditional sentence

Tags: conditionals

I'm little confused about the following real conditional sentence. The purpose of the sentence is to tell that Freedom cannot be achieved by merely chanting or dancing on the streets. Do you think any of the following are correct?

> Had freedom been achieved by howling, dancing or running around the streets, then animals in the zoo would have been out of the cages long ago.

OR

> If freedom were to be achieved by howling, dancing or running around the streets, then no animals would have been kept in cages.

Comment: The *specifics* of your example are irrelevant. What you're comparing is 1: ***Had X happened** [then Y would have happened]* and 2: ***If X were to have happened** [then Y...]*. Which should make it clearer that your second version has inconsistent tenses. It should be EITHER (counterfactual past) *If freedom **were to have been** achieved...* + ***...would have been** kept...* OR (hypothetical future) *If freedom **were to be** achieved... + ***...would be** kept...*

Comment: Note that the first ("fronted **had**") construction is rather literary / poetic. It wouldn't usually be used in conversational contexts.

Comment: Neither of your examples correctly convey the intended meaning. You can do that in many ways, but one minimal change is to start the first version with ***If freedom could be achieved...***

Comment: "You can do that in many ways" . Can you please share how can I achieve the intended meaning? Is this right? If freedom could be achieved by............... animals in zoo would have all been freed.  I know the correct or at least closest example for the first part could be..... If freedoms could be achieved by.... no nation would have spilled their blood.

Comment: Your intended meaning is similar to [***If wishes were horses, beggars would ride***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_wishes_were_horses,_beggars_would_ride). Where the text *before* the comma refers to some "counterfactual" assertion (it's not true; wishes are *not* horses), and what comes *after* the comma describes what would happen ***if the first part were to be true*** .

Comment: You could say "Were it possible to achieve...".  But FumbleFingers' proposed formulation "If freedom could be achieved..." is arguably better.

Comment: **If freedom was achieved** by blah, blah, blah, then animals **would be freed** from cages. There is also a past conditional for this, as in your first sentence.